# Как создать поле запроса данных от пользователя на самой странице, а не во всплывающих окнах и сообщениях

Tags: javascript, html

```
 function getSum(total,num) {return total + num};
 function val(yazı,harf,değer){ rgxp = new RegExp(değer,'gim'); text = 
 yazı.toLowerCase();
 if (text.indexOf(harf) > -1){ sonuc = 
  text.split(harf).join(değer).match(rgxp).map(Number).reduce(getSum) }else{ sonuc=0 };
 return sonuc;}

 String.prototype.abjad = function() {
 a = val(this,'a','1'); b = val(this,'b','2'); c = val(this,'c','3')

 return a+b+c
 };


         Ask();
         function Ask() 
        {text = prompt ('Введите текст');
        if (text != null) {
        alert("Числовое значение: " + text.abjad())  //метод вывода - сплывающее сообщение
    document.write ('Ваше число: '+ text.abjad())  //метод вывода в страницу
}
```

}

```
    Gematrical value is: <span id='+ text.abjad()'></span>

    <form name="search">
    <textarea rows="7" cols="40" name="message"></textarea>
    <div id='+ text.abjad()'></div>
    </form>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, вам нужно использовать поле input и на него уже подвешать событие change https://learn.javascript.ru/events-change про события можно прочитать тут